# Older versions of spring boot fails to start on Java 11

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm using 1.4.1.RELEASE of spring-boot application. Everything was working ok for Java 8. However when I updated java version to 11 I can't run application using command `mvn clean spring-boot:run`. At the same time I can package is successfully (using mvn package). When I set java version to 8, it's working fine again.

```
[main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Restarter has not been initialized
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:392)
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter.getInstance(Restarter.java:545)
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(RestartApplicationListener.java:48)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:166)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:138)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:121)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.contextLoaded(EventPublishingRunListener.java:85)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.contextLoaded(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:66)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:367)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175)
        at com.myapp.Application.main(Application.java:24)
```

I can understand that newer versions of Spring might require newer version of Java. But it's not clear why older spring-boot can't be run on newer java versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, *Spring Boot 1.4.1.RELEASE* requires *Java 7* until *Java 8* which is highly recommended and *Spring Framework 4.3.3.RELEASE* or above. If you want to use *Java 11* with some version of Spring Boot, The latest version is recommended to use, then you should do a upgrade your project.

> 

Although you can use Spring Boot with **Java 6** or **7**, we generally recommend **Java 8** if at all possible.

[System Requirements for Spring Boot 1.4.1](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-system-requirements)

The version of Spring Boot which starts to use `Java 11` it was `2.1.1` then you can use any up to this version.

> Spring Boot 2.1.1.RELEASE requires **Java 8** and is compatible up to **Java 11** (included).

[System Requirements for Spring Boot 2.1.1](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-system-requirements)

Answer (score 2):

The version of Spring Boot that you're using was released in September, 2016, long before Java 11 was released in September, 2018. I recommend you update to the latest version of Spring Boot, which is currently [2.1.9](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter/2.1.9.RELEASE).

Please let me know if this fixes your issue; otherwise, we'll debug it further.

Comment: 2.2.0 Is actually the latest release of spring-boot. It just hasn't been uploaded to the maven repository yet.